# Consolidating SQL records based on contiguous dates

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table of data similar to the following:

```
ID    Name    Start       End
10    Value1  2016-01-01  2016-12-31
10    Value1  2017-01-01  2017-12-31
10    Value1  2018-01-01  2018-12-31
10    Value2  2019-01-01  2019-12-31
10    Value2  2020-01-01  2020-12-31
10    Value1  2021-01-01  2021-12-31
```

I'm trying to write a SQL statement that will consolidate the records based on contiguous start and end dates where the Name is the same, e.g.

```
ID    Name    Start       End
10    Value1  2016-01-01  2018-12-31
10    Value2  2019-01-01  2020-12-31
10    Value1  2021-01-01  2021-12-31
```

A simple grouping by Name with min start date and max end date doesn't work because the Name can change to the original value. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

This is on the Snowflake platform.

Answer (score 1):

With the `x` CTE being your input data, you can use the `CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT` function to bucket your value changes, which I've done in the `cond` CTE.  Then you simply aggregate your data on the `id`, `value`, and the `cond_group` bucket that you just created.

```
with x as (
    select *
    from (values
            (10,'Value1','2016-01-01'::date,'2016-12-31'::date),
            (10,'Value1','2017-01-01'::date,'2017-12-31'::date),
            (10,'Value1','2018-01-01'::date,'2018-12-31'::date),
            (10,'Value2','2019-01-01'::date,'2019-12-31'::date),
            (10,'Value2','2020-01-01'::date,'2020-12-31'::date),
            (10,'Value1','2021-01-01'::date,'2021-12-31'::date))
            as y (id,value,start_date,end_date)
), cond as (
    select id,
           value,
           start_date,
           end_date,
           CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(value) OVER (partition by id ORDER BY start_date) as cond_group
    from x
)
select id, value, min(start_date) as start_date, max(end_date) as end_date
from cond
group by id, value, cond_group;
```